# Unable to connect to sql database only from asp

Tags: sql, asp-classic, adodb

In a VB6 program:

```
Dim conn As Object
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
conn.Open "DRIVER={SQL Server}; Server=(local)\aaa; Database=bbb; UID=ccc; PWD=ddd"
```

In an ASP program:

```
Sub ProcessSqlServer(conn)
    Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "DRIVER={SQL Server}; Server=(local)\aaa; Database=bbb; UID=ccc; PWD=ddd"
```

The VB6 program works, the ASP program does not (see error below).  I tried checking the event log for errors, but found nothing.  Or more precisely, I did find local an activation permission error, but this was fixed once I added local launch/activation permission for Network Service to the Machine Debug Manager via the component services tool.

Error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Timeout expired
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `NETWORK SERVICE` needed lots of permissions on `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp` .

Comment: Note: This fixes some stuff, but isn't the only username involved.

Comment: Other temp directories like `c:\windows\temp` may be involved, too.  It varies based on whether it is run in debug mode, among other things.